# Android data binding in fragment - IllegalArgumentException: No view found

Tags: android

I have a fragment that contains a recyclerview. This recyclerview is bound to my viewmodel using data binding.

Problem; I get the following exception trying to launch the fragment:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: no.inforte.demo, PID: 3134
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0d0074 (no.inforte.demo:id/content_frame) for fragment CategoryListFragment2{6db9671 #1 id=0x7f0d0074 CATEGORYLISTFRAGMENT}
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1059)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
    ...
    ...
```

The error states correctly that the 'content_frame' does not exist. This view is in the layout for the MainActivity.java class, as my fragment container.

Since I am using data binding I use the DataBindingUtil.setContentView method:

```
private void initDataBinding() {
    Log.d(TAG, "initDataBinding");
    mCategoryListFragmentBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(getActivity(), R.layout.category_list_fragment);
    mCategoryListViewModel = new CategoryListViewModel(mCategoryListView, getContext());
    mCategoryListFragmentBinding.setCategoryListViewModel(mCategoryListViewModel);
}
```

How to resolve?

More info:

This is how I launch this fragment from the MainActivity:

```
CategoryListFragment2 categoryListFragment = new CategoryListFragment2();
    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame, categoryListFragment, FRAGMENT_TAG_CATEGORYLIST)
            .commit();
getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
```

This is my fragment layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="no.inforte.demo.ui.fragment.CategoryListFragment2">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="categoryListViewModel"
            type="no.inforte.demo.ui.viewmodel.CategoryListViewModel" />
    </data>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/category_list"
                android:name="no.inforte.demo.ui.fragment.CategoryListFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
                tools:context="no.inforte.demo.ui.fragment.CategoryListFragment"
                tools:listitem="@layout/rowlayout_category_list">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: how did you resolved this issue?

Comment: did you got the solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also ran into this issue and found the solution using DataBindingUtil.inflate method. 
Everything you did is correct except your initDataBinding method should be removed and replaced as follows:

In your fragment class (the one that extends Fragment), you need to override the onCreateView method and do this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    CategoryListFragmentBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.category_list_fragment , container, false);
    binding.setViewModel(new CategoryListViewModel());
    return binding.getRoot();
}
```

Once you do that your data binding will work properly and you are good to go!

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't find the fragment oncreateview in the above code you shared. Think if you have not added that yet, try returns the parent view in the data binding view instant you just created in initDataBinding.